# the for loop doesn't work as what it supposed to

Tags: java

the program will ask the user for the item's code, then the program will change the item's status to unavailable. the code works fine and it changes the status but the code inside else still running and printing the item is not found

here is the code

```
public void stopSellingItem(){
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;
    String u = "Unvailable";
    do {        
        try {        
            invalidInput = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the item's code you want to stop selling it : ");
        q = s.nextInt();
        out: for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
            if(q == items[i].getCode()){
                items[i] = new Items(items[i].getCode(), items[i].getDescription(), items[i].getQuantity(),
                        items[i].getcostPrice(), items[i].getsellingPrice(),
                        u, items[i].getDiscount());
                break out;
            }else if(q != items[i].getCode()){
                System.out.println("The Item is not found");
            }
        }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid code [Numbers Only]");
            s.next();
    invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        }
} while (invalidInput);
}
```

i did all what you guys suggests but nothing worked
this is my final code which still have the same problem

```
public void stopSellingItem(){
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;
    String u = "Unvailable";
    boolean y = true;
    do {        
        try {        
            invalidInput = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the item's code you want to stop selling it : ");
        q = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){

            while(items[i].getCode()==q){
                items[i].setStatus(u);
                y = false;
                break;
            }
            if(y)
                System.out.println("The item is not found");
        }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid code [Numbers Only]");
            s.next();
    invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        }
} while (invalidInput);
}
```

Comment: Ah for the love of sanity, don't use labels...simply `break` the current loop and be done with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` is working, but you are printing `The Item is not found` because of the first items, not the last. Add a boolean to catch the case. You can then also omit the break.

```
    // add a boolean
    boolean itemFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(q == items[i].getCode()){
            items[i] = new Items(items[i].getCode(), items[i].getDescription(), items[i].getQuantity(),
                    items[i].getcostPrice(), items[i].getsellingPrice(),
                    u, items[i].getDiscount());
            itemFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (!itemFound){
        System.out.println("The Item is not found");
    }
```

Comment: +1 because this has nothing to do with the label. The else statement is just misplaced in the program logic.

Comment: @mazin move the `if(y)` out of the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

finally solved the problem with the help of "absurd-mind"

this is the code after solving it

```
public void stopSellingItem(){
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;
    String u = "Unvailable";
    boolean y = false;
    do {        
        try {        
            invalidInput = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the item's code you want to stop selling it : ");
        q = s.nextInt();
        out: for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){

            if(items[i].getCode()==q){
                items[i].setStatus(u);
                y = false;
                break out;
            }
            if(!y)
                System.out.println("The item is not found");
            break out;
        }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid code [Numbers Only]");
            s.next();
    invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        }
} while (invalidInput);
}
```

all i did is put out: in the outer loop and when i break i break from the outer loop

thanks to all

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) remove the `out` label, just use `break;` 2) move the `if (!y)` so it is *after* the `for` loop 3) This code only works if you stop selling the first item in the array (because the second `break out;` is in the `for` loop and not the `if`) 4) You are never setting `y` to `true`