# The if(!found) statement is not working properly

Tags: java

the program will ask the user to enter the code of the item he wants to search for. if the item's code exists it will print it to the screen and all works fine until here. The problem is when the user enters code that not exists, the program won't work. it doesn't print "Item not found"

here is the code

```
public void searchItem(){
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;

    do {        
        try {   
            boolean found = false;
            invalidInput = false;

            System.out.println("Enter the item's code you want to search for : ");
            q = s.nextInt();

            out: for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){

                if(q == items[i].getCode()){
                    System.out.println(items[i].toString());
                    found = true;
                    System.exit(2);
                }
                counter++;
            }
            if(!found)
                System.out.print("Item not found");


        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid code [Numbers Only]");
            s.next();
            invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        }
    } while (invalidInput);  
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. You will more easily see any errors that way.

Comment: Since, you exit the program after you find something, you can simply print not found after the loop.

Comment: Why don't you use a `break` as you have been suggested in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398247/the-for-loop-doesnt-work-as-what-it-supposed-to) ?

Comment: i tried, it didn't work

Comment: what does getCode() return? explain in detail.

Comment: "the program won't work" is a bit vague, what exactly does happen?

Comment: It works for me (when I add the missing definitions of s, counter, items etc.). What problem do you see exactly?

Comment: @mazin what is that out: that u have printed between code? plz format your code so we can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i use this (condensed form) of your code it works, and prints "Item not found" as we would expect... So the problem is somewhere else I feel....

Please provide further information about what happens if you enter a missing (but valid) item number!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;
    int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    do {
        boolean found = false;
        invalidInput = false;

        System.out.println("Enter the item's code you want to search for : ");
        q = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (q == items[i]) {
                System.out.println(items[i]);
                found = true;
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.print("Item not found");
    } while (invalidInput);
}
```